# Prevent INSERTing duplicated references to category table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm working with a Database First model with Entity Framework 5.

In particular, we have one table with a list of predefined categories that are used as reference to a second table of items.

```
TABLE ITEM
(lots of fields)
integer category_id

TABLE CATEGORY
integer category_id
string name
string description
```

The table with the categories is populated initially and will not be modified (unless there is a change in the requirements)

The category for each object is calculated inside the code and returns a `Category` object for each `Item` object passed to a class written for that purpouse. This class does not need to use the objects in the CATEGORY TABLE, because they are known in advance. It is basically something like this:

```
var calculatedCategory = Categorizer.calculateCategoryFor(itemToCategorize);
itemToCategorize.category = calculatedCategory;
```

**QUESTION**

I want to find the most transparent way to work with the entities when I am calculating the `Category` for an `Item` whatever I want to use the category inside or outside a DbContext. The method to returns a `Category` object instead of just a `String` to make a proper use of the entities even in a dettached scenario, but this category can just be created on the fly inside the method because it knows the name, wich is the important field.

The key point here is how to make it transparent to whoever uses this `Categorizer` to avoid possible duplicated insertions (besides during runtime enforcing some constrain in the DB).

The solution I am using right now is passing a collection of `categories` to the constructor of the `Categorizer`, so it can use them when they are actual references in the database. When I just want to calculate it whithout any database operation involved, I just create a collection of this `Categories` dettached. However this is an additional duplicity and cumbersome, and feels very wrong.

I would like something that could be used like this

```
using (var ctx = new context())
{
    var itemToCategorize = getItemSomeHow();
    var calculatedCategory = Categorizer.calculateCategoryFor(itemToCategorize);
    itemToCategorize.category = calculatedCategory;
    ctx.SaveChanges()
}
```

Instead of something like that

```
using (var ctx = new context())
{
    var itemToCategorize = getItemSomeHow();
    var calculatedCategory = Categorizer.calculateCategoryFor(itemToCategorize);
    //Code that searches for the matching category in the DB
...
    itemToCategorize.category = matchingCategory;
    ctx.SaveChanges()
}
```

and avoid the returned `Category` to be inserted as a new one in the database, and just update the reference of the `Item` to the right preexisting `Category`

I'm thinking in two approaches:

1. Override some methods in the model to do this verification and avoid inserts in the database in the Category table.
2. Modify the database to remove the category_id and use the name field as primary key (the problem here is that I'm not an expert in databases and I don't know the effects in the preformance of this, as the ITEMS TABLE can be huge)

Comment: Just modify your calculateCategoryFor method to get the category from the context...

Comment: I would like to use it both with an active context and outside a context. I dont need the categories from the database as that's something hard coded, so the Categorizer itself shouldn't need access to the context

Comment: Then just get the category from the context in your method where you are saving the item, and keep your categorizer as it is... IT can still return a category entity, but you can just use that to retrieve it from the context.

Comment: I wouldn't use string primary keys *physically*, but in the mappings for EF you can pretend that name is the primary key. EF doesn't have to know the real surrogate key. Esp. is the latter is auto-generated you can hide it from EF altogether.

Comment: @GertArnold seems like that would be a good thing to try. Could you elaborate on how to link the EF keys to that string? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, that's harder than it appeared. Doing so, `Item` should have something like a `CategoryName` property to serve as foreign key. But, something else, why don't you just always work with generated categories, offline and online?

Comment: I want to avoid inserting duplicated categories. If I generate the `Category`, if they are added as a reference to `Item`, when adding the objects, it will insert the whole graph, including the generated categories, I wouldn't like to leave the responsability of updating instead inserting  to the consumer of the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid having to do some sort of name checking before storing a `Category`. I think the cheapest way to do this is:

```
var categoryId = ctc.Categories.Where(c => c.Name == category.Name)
                    .Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault();

if (categoryId.HasValue)
{
    itemToCategorize.CategoryId = categoryId.Value;
}
else
{
    ctc.Categories.Add(category);
    itemToCategorize.Category = category;
}
```

So you only fetch an Id value from the database to do the check. And by setting `CategoryId` only (not the `Category` object reference) you avoid ever duplicating an existing `Category`.

To prevent concurrency issues due to latency between the check and the actual insert, of course as a final guard there should be a unique index on the name column (needless to say, I guess).

Comment: I'm not so concerned about the code to match the generated `Category` as about how to enforce this constrain in the code (I feel that enforcing this just in the database would serve as the last defense, but will only be detected during integration tests at best). Would it make sense to implement this matching overriding the SaveChanges method in the same fashion than in this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/using-entity-framework-with-an-existing-database-data-access/)?:. See _Dealing with properties best dealt with at the Data Layer_